# Find node having max value in a specific binary tree such that at odd level, lChild>parentNode & rChild<parentNode. Vice-versa at even level

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

Find node having max value in a binary tree.
**Binary Tree Constraint:** Each node contains a distinct natural number in such a way that, at each odd level, left child is smaller than the immediate parent node and right child is greater than the immediate parent node. Vice-versa at even level. That is at each even level, left child is greater than the immediate parent node and right child is smaller than the immediate parent node.Also, suppose that level starts with 1. I have been asked this in a interview.

My Solution: BFS traverse the binary tree and find the max value. I know this is not optimal solution but, interviewer wants the optimized solution.

class TreeNode{

```
int data;
TreeNode left, right;

TreeNode(int data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}

int findMax(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    int max = root.data;
    Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    queue.add(root);
    while (queue.size() != 0) {
        TreeNode node = queue.poll();
        if (node.data > max) {
            max = node.data;
        }
        if (node.left != null) {
            queue.add(node.left);
        }
        if (node.right != null) {
            queue.add(node.right);
        }
    }
    return max;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(6);
    newNode.left = new TreeNode(3);
    newNode.right = new TreeNode(7);
    newNode.left.left = new TreeNode(10);
    newNode.left.right = new TreeNode(2);
    newNode.right.left = new TreeNode(8);
    newNode.right.right = new TreeNode(5);
    int maxValue = newNode.findMax(newNode);
    System.out.println(maxValue);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the optimal solution, but I can think of one way to optimize it. That would be to only traverse, or add to your queue, the node that you know will be greater than the current root node. This is because we know at each level, depending on if it's odd or even, only side of each node is certain to be greater.

To implement this you would need to initiate a counter before your 'while' loop, to either 0 or 1 depending on if you consider the root level to be 1 or 0. 
Then with each iteration, you would check whether or not your counter is even by seeing if count%2==0.  If it's 0, then it's even, and you can be sure that only the left node may be greater, so you can queue it for comparison. If count%2==1 then you are on an odd level, and can be sure that only the right node may be greater, and queue it.

While doing this comparison you should still check for null before queuing. And in that same iteration, don't forget to increment count! I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution would be if we assume:

odd level: left "SUBTREE"(not just child) < root < right Subtree (not just child)

even level : left "SUBTREE"(not just child) > root > right Subtree (not just child).

Basically leveled BST!

```
public static int level = 1;

static TreeNode findMaxNode(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return root;
    }
    if (level % 2 == 0) {
        // EVEN LEVEL
        // root.right < root < root.left
        if (root.left == null) {
            return root;
        } else {
            level++;
            return findMaxNode(root.left);
        }
    }
    if (level % 2 != 0) {
        // ODD level
        // root.left < root < root.right

        if (root.right == null) {
            return root;
        } else {
            level++;
            return findMaxNode(root.right);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {


    TreeNode n9 = new TreeNode(60, null, null);
    TreeNode n10 = new TreeNode(45, null, null);

    TreeNode n8 = new TreeNode(50, n9, n10);

    TreeNode n6 = new TreeNode(40, null, n8);
    TreeNode n7 = new TreeNode(26, null, null);

    TreeNode n4 = new TreeNode(22, null, null);
    TreeNode n5 = new TreeNode(10, null, null);

    TreeNode n2 = new TreeNode(20, n4, n5);
    TreeNode n3 = new TreeNode(30, n6, n7);

    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(25, n2, n3); // Level 1

    System.out.println(findMaxNode(root));
}
```